# Is there a way to combine these queries and calculations?

Tags: php, mysql

Currently my code is working as intended, but there are 3 queries for each time a user makes an action. I have to imagine there is a way to reduce this to 2 or even 1 query, to reduce the load on the server.

```
$qry = "SELECT 
    `team`.`teamlist` AS 'team' 
FROM  
    `user`  
INNER JOIN 
    `team` 
ON 
    `user`.`team` = `team`.`teamid` 
WHERE 
    `user`.`userid` = " . $userid; 
$result = $db->query_first($qry);
```

The first query is grabbing the "active team" for the given user, and getting a string that stores the team member ids in a form like `4,7,8,10`. I know that standard practice would be to have team_id on each team member's table, and then join tables that way. But this is how the current system is set up, and I will have to revise many lines of code to implement it that way.

```
$vals = explode(',',$result['team']); 
$ids = implode("','",$vals);
```

This basically just adds single quotes around each value, for the next query.

```
$qry2 = "SELECT  
    `indv`.`indvid` AS 'id',  
    `indv`.`level` AS 'level',  
    `indv`.`exp` AS 'exp' 
FROM   
    `indv`   
WHERE  
    `indv`.`indvid` IN ('" . $ids . "')"; 
$result2 = $db->query_read($qry2);
```

Here I use the team list to grab information about the individual team members. I guess having that alternative structure might make combining the top two queries easier, as I could be searching where `indv.teamid = user.team`.

```
while($resultLoop = $db->fetch_array($result2)) {  
  $lvl = $resultLoop['level']; 
  $next_lvl = round((($lvl+1)*($lvl+1))/2,0); 
  $rlvl = ($resultLoop['exp'] == $next_lvl-1) ? $lvl+1 : $lvl; 
  $str .= "when `indvid` = " . $resultLoop['id'] . " then " . $rlvl . "  
"; 
}
```

This is the main part that I'd like to do entirely in SQL. It's a relatively simple formula that applies to every individual team member.

```
$qry3 = "UPDATE `indv` 
    SET `level` = (case " . $str . " 
                    end), 
        `exp` = `exp` + 1 
    WHERE `indvid` in ('" . $ids . "')"; 
$db->query_write($qry3);
```

The final query in practice looks like this:

```
UPDATE 
    `indv` 
SET 
    `level` = (case when `indvid` = 13 then 4 
                    when `indvid` = 16 then 4 
                    when `indvid` = 29 then 4 
                    when `indvid` = 32 then 5 
                    when `indvid` = 34 then 4 
                    when `indvid` = 48 then 6 
                end), 
    `exp` = `exp` + 1 
WHERE 
    `indvid` in ('13','16','29','32','34','48')
```

When I have more time I do plan to revise everything to use a teamid on the `indv` table. Assuming I made that change, is there a way that all of these queries could be combined into one?

Comment: I know it again would involve a lot of editing (a programmers curse), but I think you should pay more attention to your _names_. In the database you have a table called `team`, it contains a column called `teamid`, that's all understandable, but then in the `user` table you have a column called `team`, which seem to refer to `team.teamid`. OK, unusual, but just acceptable. However, in your first query you give `team`.`teamlist` the alias `team`. Oh my, now we have a table, a referrer and a list, all with the same name. Say what?! I am getting confused.

Comment: I'm sorry, I changed the names from long ones to something short in the hopes that the example would become MORE understandable, not LESS. I guess in my rush, I made things worse.

Comment: Yes, you did. :-) Personally I really don't like unnecessary abbreviations. They don't make your code faster, or easier to read. Yes, 30 years ago when we had 64KB of main memory, abbreviations were useful, but not now. Examples: `qry`, `indv`, `exp`, `lvl`, `rlvl`. Please don't do this. We're humans, not machines.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: It is mysqli through vbulletin, and the only input here is a numerical userid which is assigned upon registration. No one manually specifies any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try subquery to merge result of 1st and 2nd query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM `table_name`)
```

So your query will looks like

```
SELECT  
 `indv`.`indvid` AS 'id',  
 `indv`.`level` AS 'level',  
 `indv`.`exp` AS 'exp' 
FROM   
 `indv`   
WHERE  
 `indv`.`indvid` IN (SELECT 
 `team`.`teamlist` AS 'team' 
FROM  
 `user`  
INNER JOIN 
 `team` 
ON 
 `user`.`team` = `team`.`teamid` 
WHERE 
 `user`.`userid` = " . $userid)";
```

Comment: This is not very helpful, I think. This is virtually the same as executing multiple queries. The question is how to combine, or join, the queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put the first query inside the second query and remove the php operation to add single quotes by doing.

```
SELECT  
    `indv`.`indvid` AS 'id',  
    `indv`.`level` AS 'level',  
    `indv`.`exp` AS 'exp' 
FROM   
    `indv`   
WHERE  
    `indv`.`indvid` IN 
(
SELECT 
    `team`.`teamlist`
FROM  
    `user`  
INNER JOIN 
    `team` 
ON 
    `user`.`team` = `team`.`teamid` 
WHERE 
    `user`.`userid` = $userid
)
```

Comment: A simple solution, but not much quicker than two seperate queries. A proper join, with the right indexes, would be better.